# Save textarea to HTML file on local server

Tags: php, html, forms, save, ckeditor

In CKEditor, I have a very basic page that has one form on it. The form has one element - textarea - where my user can create HTML

I want my user to be able to click a button on the screen and that "Save As" box opens up with the ability to save the contents of that textarea to a HTML file on their local server.

My code so far is pretty much just this:

```
<form method="post">
   <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
   <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
   </script>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the text to a php file.

In the php file you set the following headers:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somename.html");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

After that you simply output the html from the editor.